# REGEX: Extract latitude and longitude from Google Maps static image url

Tags: regex

I want latitude and longitude from this string, representing an url (latitude and longitude are the numbers between ?center= and &zoom):

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.390400788244364,-3.689793032995914&zoom=16&size=710x440&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&markers=color:red%7C40.390400788244364,-3.689793032995915

I'm using this regex:

```
http:\/\/maps\.google\.com\/maps\/api\/staticmap\?center=(\d),(\d)&zoom=[[:ascii:]]+
```

But not getting any results. My regex skills are rusty...

Any clues?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: **This might not be a job for regexes, but for existing tools in your language of choice.**  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings. You probably want to use existing code that has already been written, tested, and debugged.

In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.

Perl: [`URI` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/).

Ruby: [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html).

.NET: ['Uri' class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
center=(-?[\d]*\.[\d]*),(-?[\d]*\.[\d]*)&
```

[image]

[Code sample](https://regex101.com/r/kL3eO1/2)

Answer (score 3):

This simpler version worked for me (used it in javascript) when the map links is shorter as well like this:

> https://maps.google.com/maps?q=19.340742111206055%2C-99.21727752685547&z=17&hl=es

I'm using this regex to extract the coordinates set.

```
[-]?[\d]+[.][\d]*
```

I end up with this:

```
19.340742,-99.217278
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use this to exclude center and the & symbol.

```
(?<=\=)([\-]?[\d]*\.[\d]*),([\-]?[\d]*\.[\d]*)(?=&)
```

I should mention in a few languages it's actually this

```
(?=)([\-]?[\d]*\.[\d]*),([\-]?[\d]*\.[\d]*)(?=&)
```

This will leave you with

```
40.390400788244364,-3.689793032995914
```

without "center=" and without "&" on the end

Answer (score 1):

Your regex didn't match because of `(\d),(\d)`. Each group captures a single digit.

```
http:\/\/maps\.google\.com\/maps\/api\/staticmap\?center=(\d),(\d)&zoom=[[:ascii:]]+
                                                           ↑    ↑
```

But you want to match one or more out of minus, period and digit. Use `([-\d.]+)` instead of `(\d)`

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/dH7uT7/1) with your updated regex at regex101.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Regex in this case would be to simply split the string until you get what you want, since the URL structure stays the same before the latitude value.

In python for example, you can do :

```py
my_url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.390400788244364,-3.689793032995914&zoom=16&size=710x440&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&markers=color:red%7C40.390400788244364,-3.689793032995915'

lat_long = my_url.split('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=')[1].split('&zoom')[0].split(',')

print(lat_long)
Out: ['40.390400788244364', '-3.689793032995914']
```