# How to get longitude and latitude From Google Maps location Link?

Tags: vb.net, google-maps

i have this link in textbox1.text= "https://www.google.com.sa/maps/@27.9150521,42.3643235,15z?hl=ar"

i want get lat= 27.9150521 and lang = 42.3643235

I am Use GMap.NET in vb.net

Any help please

Comment: I suggest that you use regex. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33614816/5844572) seems to have cracked that problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

.NET can parse URLs:

```
Dim u as new Uri("https://www.google.com.sa/maps/@27.9150521,42.3643235,15z?hl=a")

Dim latLong = u.Segments.Last().Trim("@"c).Split(","c)
```

latLong is now a 3-length string array with the lat/long/height(?)

`Last()` requires you to `Imports System.Linq`